# Getting different result StringBuilder vs String using recusrion in JAVA

Tags: java, string, recursion, stringbuilder

When I am running below code with StringBuilder as parameter, I am getting different output:

```
public static List<String> generateParenthesis(int n) {
        if(n==0)
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        generate(list, new StringBuilder(), 0, 0, n);
        return list;
    }
    public static void generate(List<String> list, StringBuilder s, int j, int k, int n)
    {
        if(s.length()>2*n || j>n || k>n || k>j)
            return;
        if(s.length()==2*n && j==n && k==n)
        {
            list.add(s.toString());
            return;
        }
        if(j<n)
        {
            generate(list, s.append("("), j+1, k, n);
        }
        if(k<j)
        {
            generate(list, s.append(")"), j, k+1, n);
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT: [((()))]

Where as when I am running same code with param as String, I am getting different output:

```
        if(n==0)
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        generate(list, "", 0, 0, n);
        return list;
    }
    public static void generate(List<String> list, String s, int j, int k, int n)
    {
        if(s.length()>2*n || j>n || k>n || k>j)
            return;
        if(s.length()==2*n && j==n && k==n)
        {
            list.add(s.toString());
            return;
        }
        if(j<n)
        {
            generate(list, s+"(", j+1, k, n);
        }
        if(k<j)
        {
            generate(list, s+")", j, k+1, n);
        }
    }
```

Output: [((())), (()()), (())(), ()(()), ()()()]

Can anyone help me to understand why is this happening?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is simply that `String` is immutable: Whenever you concatenate or otherwise manipulate a `String` object, you are really creating a new `String` object with the new value.

`StringBuilder` however is mutable: you *can* change the value of any given `StringBuilder` instance (that's basically the main reason for its existence).

So in this line:

```
generate(list, s.append("("), j+1, k, n);
```

You

1. modify the `StringBuilder` instace
2. call `generate`
3. still have the modified `StringBuilder` after the call

But in

```
generate(list, s+"(", j+1, k, n);
```

you instead

1. create a *new* `String` with a new value
2. call `generate`, passing that new value
3. have `s` still reference the previous value after the `generate` call.